# How to get started learning blues guitar?

Tags: guitar, blues

I am totally new to blues guitar and I am keen to learn blues guitar and form my own blues band.

However, I am confused where to start. I look up youtubes and the lessons are all over the place. Not sure which to learn first. Scale first ? Chord first ? Or something outside first ? Is there a more systematic approach to learn similar to learning classical where there is a specific syllabus and students learn level by level. It seems most blues guitar lessons just jump right in to learn scales, shuffles, etc.. and even talked about improvisation.

Comment: What can you play on guitar now?

Answer (score 0):

Are you completely new to guitar? I'm going to assume you are not for this answer.

I would say you should first listen to as much blues music as you can and try to pick out songs/artists that resonate with you. Once you have a small collection, start learning their songs, focusing on feeling. You can use tab, tutorial, or your ear.

As you learn these songs go ahead and practice improvising over a standard twelve bar blues. You can find backing tracks for this sort of thing all over youtube. I'd recommend just using a pentatonic scale based on the tonic note to start, but you'll soon want to try something else. Remember, many blues greats made careers off of that formula, so try and squeeze as much creativity as you can out of that formula. Again, rhythm and feel are your friend.

The twelve bar blues is not the be-all end-all of the blues. There are other blues traditions that come from different regions of the south. Depending on what artists you like, you may want to explore these styles deeper.

You can do all of these at once, they do not need to be in a strict sequence like classical education might be. When you get tired of learning a song, improvise over a progression. Take some time and just play rhythm, no lead. Listen to BB King, Robert Johnson, Muddy Waters, etc. Have fun :)